# Javascript null object type

Tags: javascript

I found this in JS articles, but i can't find explanation, can someone point to wright direction or explain here?

```
typeof null; // object
null === Object; // false
```

Comment: All in javascript is an object, but you can't compare a null value with an object reference. Comparison should be `typeof null === "object"`

Comment: typeof null === Object still false

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null)

Comment: You have to read up some very very basic concepts. like: what is a constructor? What is a value, what is a reference? Comparison: equality vs. identity, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `Object` is a function. Therefore null is just null and Object is a function.

```
typeof null === 'object'
typeof Object === 'function'
```

Answer (score 1):

MDN explain it thus:

> The value null is a JavaScript literal representing null or an "empty" value, i.e. no object value is present. It is one of JavaScript's primitive values.
>
> The value null is a literal

Further down that page you'll find this:

```
typeof null        // object (bug in ECMAScript, should be null)
typeof undefined   // undefined
null === undefined // false
null  == undefined // true
```

Here is a codepen with that very code, showing the results (and the bug talked about)

```js
document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = typeof null;
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = typeof undefined;
document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML = null === undefined;
document.getElementById('test4').innerHTML = null == undefined;
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<div id="test3"></div>
<div id="test4"></div>
```