# What does it mean to say that "null is a literal" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

`undefined` is a global variable which has the value `undefined` — a datatype by itself which can have only one value. But what is the value `null`?

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null):

> The value null is a literal.

What does that mean?

I know literal as "something you write fixed into your code". Like x = 3 + 4.

Here 3 and 4 would be integer-literals. But I don't get that together with what the MDN documentation says.

Comment: [Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Literals)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're dead right. I was reading about it this morning on the way to work, and got it all mixed up :-(... ah well, it will stick now

Comment: Duplicate: [Javascript null object type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007247/javascript-null-object-type/36007691#36007691)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert but I think you already have the answer: you said 3 and 4 are "integer-literal". Quoting wikipedia:

> In computer science, a literal is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code.

So  `3` and `4` are both literals, as well as `34` or `"hello"`. `null` is a literal in the same way, but instead of representing a number or a string, is has a meaning of nothingness.

EDIT: As I said, I am no expert and it seems I am not quite right about literals. T.J. Crowder explains it much better than me, [see his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36173108/3824918)

Comment: *"A literal is a member of the language itself"* - No it isn't. 3 and 4 aren't really "members of the language itself".

Comment: @nnnnnn I'd like to understand, what can we call them then ? I see them as atomic elements of the language, isn't it what a literal is ?

Comment: A literal is essentially a hard-coded value. Not a variable,  but a specific value that is *literally* spelled out. Perhaps I interpreted your answer in a way you didn't intend, but I wouldn't say that the numeric literal `3` or the string literal `"hello"` are elements of the language - but the syntax that lets you include them in your program *is* part of the language. If that's what you meant then I apologise.

Comment: I see what you meant, and that is indeed what I had in mind, though I did not put it as clear as you! The `"hello"` example is a good one, as it _is_ a literal, but at the same time the word itself is not part of the language. Thank you for the explanation, I'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 13):

Literals are just a way to write values in our code. `null`, the thing you actually type, is a literal that defines the value `null`, just like `1` is a literal that defines the value 1. The `null` *value* is just that: A value (the only value in the Null type), like 1 is a value (one of many values in the Number type).

Remember that MDN is a community-edited resource. It's usually pretty good, but it comes down to who wrote and/or subsequently edited the page. Sometimes the terminology is a bit off. Let's look at the opening sentence of that page as it was when you posted your question:

> The value `null` is a JavaScript literal representing null or an "empty" value, i.e. no object value is present.

Yeah, that looks like an editing error. It should read something like:

> The value `null` represents the intentional absence of any object value.

<s>I'll probably edit it later.</s> I've edited it and the subsequent line that's trying to highlight that `null` is a literal, not an identifier for a property on the global object like `undefined` can be.

Comment: Can you explain how the terminology is **off** in that MDN page? That is not clear to me. Anything wrong in saying *value of null is a literal*?

Comment: _"Remember that MDN is a community-edited resource. It's usually pretty good, but it comes down to who wrote and/or subsequently edited the page."_ Good point; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content

Comment: @sabithpocker: Yes, that would be incorrect. A *value* cannot be a *literal*. A literal, again, is something you type in your code to represent a specific value. You use literals to represent values in your code (e.g., `console.log(42)` uses the characters 4 and 2 next to each other as a literal to represent the value 42), but values are not literals.

Comment: Understood :) Thanks. Also, the line below that explains what the author is trying to explain  "*The value null is a literal (**not a property of the global object like undefined can be**).*"

Comment: @sabithpocker: Ah, yes, well observed. What the author wants to say there is "The value `null` is written with a literal, `null`; it's not a property of the global object like `undefined` can be."

Answer (score 1):

`Null` is one of the primitives in JS.

This primitive type is used as a literal in some cases which need to represent an absence of a value in a variable or reference.

However said, the literal value of `null` has a special meaning.

Point worth noting is that:

```
typeof null        // object (bug in ECMAScript, should be null)
typeof undefined   // undefined
null === undefined // false
null  == undefined // true
```

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not an object , has no methods , and is absent of any value

See [`Null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Null)

> In computer science, a null value represents a reference that points,
>   generally intentionally, to a nonexistent or invalid object or
>   address. The meaning of a null reference varies among language
>   implementations.
>
> In JavaScript, null is one of the primitive values.

---

> [Primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)
>
> A primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not
>   an object and has no methods

---

> [4.3.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-null-value) null value
>
> primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object
>   value
>
> [4.3.13](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-null-type) Null type
>
> type whose sole value is the `null` value